# Error "init registries failed, check your registry files." when compiling UNO add-in after switching to LibreOffice from OpenOffice

Tags: java, openoffice.org, libreoffice, uno

Having switched my development setup to LibreOffice 4 (from OpenOffice 3.3), the development of UNO add-ins (using Eclipse on MacOS X) fails with the exception "init registries failed, check your registry files". Why?

By switching development setup I mean that I changed the ant build files to reference the LibreOffice ure-link folder instead of the OpenOffice ure-link folder.

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice 4 for MacOS X (maybe also in other versions or in all version of LibreOffice) the location of the `offapi.rdb` file has change (compared to OpenOffice). While most (all except `offapi.rdb`) files stayed in their position somewhere below the ure-link folder which is in `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/ure-link` the offapi.rdb now resides in `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/types`.

Setting the correct path in the build.xml fixed the problem.

The path `base-link/ure-link` is now just `ure-link`.